# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _firebase_util_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.getModular Instance) (...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

[when I am trying to deploy this error popup in my console here is the image of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOBfz.jpg)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.